# x[i].parentElement.NodeName works on everything but explorer. Why?

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I'm parsing through an XML file from an XMLHttpRequest:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {      
    loadItems(this);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "articles.xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function loadItems(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var items = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
  for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    //Next line is where the script crashes...
    var newCategory = articles[i].parentElement.nodeName;
    alert(newCategory);
  }
}
```

I've tracked down my bug to the line with:

```
var newCategory = articles[i].parentElement.nodeName;
```

The XML structure I'm working with:

```
<head>
   <category>
       <item>
          <title>
             foo
          </title>
          <contents>
             bar
          </contents>
        </item>
   </category>
   <newcategory>
       <item>
          <title>
             left
          </title>
          <contents>
             right
          </contents>
        </item>
   </newcategory>
</head>
```

This seems to work in every other browser except Internet Explorer where the script silently crashes at this line. In other browsers newCategory will have a string "category" or "newcategory" depending on the parent node of each item.

I've looked at Windows' docs and they say both parentElement and nodeName accessors are supported so why would make the script crash in IE?

Comment: What do you mean it "works?" What do you mean when it doesn't "work?"

Comment: I should rephrase, I mean it successfully completes/carries out everything in the script. Otherwise it silently crashes in IE at that line.

Comment: that can hardly come as no surprise, because IE invented it But first you need to give us enough data so that we can reproduce your error. "works"/ "doesn't work", is not what we can see through. The cause of the problem mat be as remote as using a wrong doctype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some research into the Internet Explorer docs, I found that there is a parentNode accessor which will work in Firefox/Chrome/Opera and Explorer.

```
var newCategory = articles[i].parentNode.nodeName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Try using `.nodeValue` instead of `.nodeName`.

```
var newCategory = articles[i].parentElement.nodeValue;
```

Comment: The problem is I don't want the contents of the node. I want what It is actually called I.E. "category" or "newcategory".

Comment: You can do something like: `articles[i].parentElement.attributes[0].nodeName` or `articles[i].attributes[0].name`